# Sequelize in Koa - Do I need to manually close db connection on web server shutdown?

Tags: express, sequelize.js, koa

I'm using sequelize (MySQL) with Koa. When web server processes exit (such as during deployment), do I need to manually close the connection pool? What's the best practice here (doesn't have to be specific to Koa)?

Right now I'm not doing anything to close the connection pool. Occasionally, I get timeout when acquiring db connection - unsure if it's a related issue.